# Get phone card balance using J2ME

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

Is it possible to get phone card balance using J2ME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No** , Its isn't possible directly,

However you can use some webservices which can connect you to your provider and if they provide  you balance over the webservice/API